# R 3.4.1 Console Interface Very Slow on Mac

Tags: r, macos, macos-sierra

I have upgraded R from 3.3.3 to 3.4.1 and am finding that typing text directly into the R Console quickly becomes very laggy, even when R isn't using a lot of resources. I have observed this behavior running the last couple versions of macos sierra (10.12.6, etc.).

It is notable that R functions are not particularly slow when executed. Most of the time I use Textmate 2 to pass code to the console and the code passed in this fashion runs without delay.

I've done extensive searching, but I haven't found anyone else reporting this problem. I've found this behavior on two different macs: 2013 Macbook 13" and 2017 Macbook 15" and have encountered the same problem.

Is there an easy solution to this problem that I'm missing?

Comment: Exact same issue. It works fine at the beginning, then really slows down after I've run some stuff.

Comment: Does the problem occur from the very get-go, with base R? Could a library be causing a hangup? Looking around, syntax highlighting seemed like a possible culprit, but shouldn't be a problem with base R. Are you both running the 64-bit version?

Comment: @Jordan, yes, 64-bit version and base R, version 3.4.1. For me, it runs normally at the beginning, but then after I have run some stuff, it slows down substantially. Even having a delay when you push up to load the previous command. I'm not sure if it's related, but sometimes R also becomes nonresponsive when I go to save or load a file (when doing so using one of the buttons on the program as opposed to doing so with code).

Comment: Could you provide us with more details about your system?  Simply type `sessionInfo()` in your console and post the output.

Comment: @bill999, which OS version are you running? See my comment above.

Comment: @JosephWood
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: @bill999 I'm wondering if it could be an OS thing. Anywho, it might be worth contacting `r-devel@r-project.org`.

Comment: This is probably a Sierra problem. R only officially supports El Capitan. I had this problem running an older 13" macbook (running Sierra) that is now out of commission. I've replaced it with a newer macbook and the problem persists. The unfortunate problem is that a downgrade is not possible. I think that the problem is related to the move away from Apple as of R 3.4.0 due to Apple's unwillingness to support open source. That said, I have even tried compiling R myself and get the same result.

Comment: @bill999 There is nothing to be done here. Report the issue to the R-devel mailing list.

Answer (score 8):

The only answer I have been able to find is to roll back R to version 3.3.3, which is the last version before R began using Clang and GNU Fortran to compile the executable (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/ for more info).

This is not an optimal solution since I have to go back to previous versions of some packages I use (which is further complicated by the hunt for the right version of problematic dependencies). I have been looking through the r-devel threads and don't see a discussion of this, which surprises me because I know that I can't be the only person dealing with this. I will contact the r-devel folks and will update here if I get any additional info.

**Update**

The discussion on this question has identified that the issue is with the macos R GUI. Unfortunately, it appears that the R GUI developers are aware of this issue, but it is not being listed as a bug. The developers suggest clearing the console – not a workable solution for me given how quickly the problem crops up.

I have come up with a better solution, though it is kind of odd. I realized that since the problem is with the GUI and not R, you can take an old version of the GUI (they are available from the [R macos development page](http://r.research.att.com/)). I was hoping to be able to use [GUI version 1.69](http://r.research.att.com/mavericks/R-3.3-branch/R-GUI-7430-3.3-mavericks-Debug.dmg), but this caused a crash immediately. [version 1.68](http://r.research.att.com/mavericks/R-3.2-branch/R-GUI-7291-3.2-mavericks-Debug.dmg) on the other hand does work.

I installed R 3.4.1 on my computer and then downloaded the binary file for GUI version 1.68 and copied it into my applications folder (you don't have to do this, but if you do, make sure to rename the program because otherwise you will replace R). I think opened R via the GUI and loaded R 3.4.1 on R Mac GUI version 1.68. So far it seems to be working fine, confirming that the problem is indeed in the GUI.

Comment: I can confirm indeed that you're not the only one. I have the same issue (despite being on El Capitan). I ended up switching to RStudio, which works correctly actually (meaning it's really just the R Gui 1.7 for Mac shipped with R 3.4 that has an issue for me, I think).

Comment: I don't like to use RStudio (it's not bad, but I prefer Textmate), but your suggestion inspired me to try loading R 3.4.1 using a different version of the macos GUI.

Answer (score 6):

The issue actually appeared long ago (at R3.1.2 release) once the developers started to use a newer version of Xcode (I think they moved from v.5 to v.8 and above). At that time Simon told me that this is Xcode and Apple's problem, so they can't do anything about it. He did however forced the compilation with an older Xcode which "avoided" the issue till R3.4. I presume they can no longer use this work-around.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. This seems to be a common problem with open source software and Apple these days. Inkscape has a problem with two displays in macos that developers for that program also say can only be fixed by amending xcode. The workaround that I have come up with is to install an older version of the gui on top of the latest version of R and launch that program when I want to use the R console (I describe this in my post below). The gui just looks for whatever version of R is installed and interfaces with that. It is inelegant but it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to launch 1.68 version on High Sierra, which means I am relegated to use R from terminal. Not the worst choice though (I don't like Rstudio)...

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

Try running: `rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))` This should remove everything from your R console, including hidden objects.

Then run `.rs.restartR()`, which will restart R. Hopefully, whatever is clogging up the program will be gone.

Comment: You could also try running `gc()`, which should prompt R to return some memory to the operating system. Long shot, but shouldn't hurt.

Comment: I tried both `gc()` and `rm(...)` and unfortunately neither worked. For some reason `.rs.restartR()` didn't work. I closed it and opened it instead.

Comment: This does work, but it is annoying that we have to do this. I'd like to be able to help fix this problem without hacks like this, but it's unfortunately beyond my ability.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried RStudio? I highly recommend that GUI to work with R.

If you need more speed you should considering using R with modified matrix products. For example, to use R with openBLAS I wrote a tutorial here: http://pacha.hk/2017-07-12_r_and_python_via_homebrew.html